# Not able to upload file - Error:undefined - Angular Js

Tags: angularjs

How to use file upload option in Angular Js? I added a file control, and added method in `controller.js` to get the file details and pass to the `service.js`. However, I am getting error as undefined. The error is in the `controller.js` file, where i am not able to pass the correct data to the service.

I have tried the below code, but I am getting error as undefined

`index.html`:

```
<form name="mainForm" id="createForm" ng-submit="mainForm.$valid && add()" novalidate>
 <div>
<input type="file" class="form-control" id="imageUploadfile" name="imageUploadfile" accept="image/*" />
<input type="button" name="imageUploadButton" ng-click="uploadFiles()" value="Upload" />
 </div>
```

`controller.js`:

```
$scope.uploadFiles = function () {
    var f = document.getElementById('imageUploadfile').files[0],
     r = new FileReader();
    r.onloadend = function (e) {
        var data = e.target.result;

    }
    r.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
    myAPIService.postUploadImage(r).success(function (response) {
        var imageurl = _testBaseUrl + 'Images/' + response.filePath.split(/(\\|\/)/g).pop();
        $scope.testTypeImage_url = imageurl;
    }).error(function (response) {
        alert(response.responseText);
    });

    };
```

`service.js`:

```
myAPIService.postUploadImage = function (formdata) {
        var request = {
            url: urlBase + 'UploadImage',
            method: 'POST',
            data: formdata,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': undefined
            }

        }
        return $http(request);
    };
```

How to fix this? Thanks

Comment: Which line you got the error?

Comment: Not exactly sure of the line. I believe,   r.onloadend = function (e) {
        var data = e.target.result;     
         }
    var test = r.readAsArrayBuffer(f);  // test is coming as undefined

Comment: Maybe it's a typo - `onloadend` should be `onloaded`. Also `'Content-Type': undefined` looks quite suspicious. You either set a known content-type or leave it unset in the headers.

Comment: I tried the onloaded, still getting undefined

Comment: How to fix this? Thanks